# Mouseover/MouseOut jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I realize how simple this question should be to answer but I am in a medication fog and the answer is escaping me.

I would like to make this into a simple function to display specific text if the value of the text box is empty upon mouseout and to empty out the text value upon mouseover.

What I have right now that works but is very ugly:

```
$(".disappearOnClick").live('mouseover',function() {    
            if($(this).val() === 'BFA Offset') {
                $(this).val('')
            }
        });

    $(".disappearOnClick").live('mouseout',function() {
            if($(this).val() === '') {
                $(this).val('BFA Offset')
            }
        });
```

Comment: you are missing semicolon javascript

Comment: the semicolon is not required unless this is all on 1 line.

Comment: You can use `hover` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`. Syntax: `$(element).hover(function_on_hover, function_on_mouseout);`

Comment: @RobW but what about the `live()` function ? can you combine `live()` and `hover()` ?

Comment: Are you using `live` to bind events for the future? If not, use a plain `hover`. Otherwise, I recommend ManseUK's method.

Comment: @kamui "the semicolon is not required unless this is all on 1 line." dear god save us all.

Comment: @jbabey This was in response to Hira's comment, javaScript unlike c#, c++, PHP and a host of other languages does not require the semi-colon, it may be good practice, and personally I always end a command with one, but it is not required. If the code was written as it is written now, which offers readability then it is not required. However as I was pointing out if you minified your code you would need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind to multiple events using the  `live()` method - so you could use something like this ->

```
$('.disappearOnClick').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
     if($(this).val() === 'BFA Offset') {
            $(this).val('');
        }
  } else {
    if($(this).val() === '') {
            $(this).val('BFA Offset');
        }
  }
});
```

Comment: plz can you tell why there is no need of semi colon in $(this).val('')?

Comment: @Hira http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf - **7.9 Automatic Semicolon Insertion** and following

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".disappearOnClick").mouseover(function(){...});
```

and

```
$(".disappearOnClick").mouseout(function(){...});
```

Would work just as well.

Comment: but that doesnt for for newly created DOM elements with the class `disappearOnClick` ie your missing the `live()` function !!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `hover` instead:

```
$(".disappearOnClick").hover(
    function(){
        //mouseover
    },
    function(){
        //mouseout
    }
);
```

Comment: what about the live functionality ?

Comment: You could do it that way too. You could also use `bind` as well.

Comment: What i meant was the OP was using the `live()` function - ie it listens to the event on newly create DOM elements - how can you use `live()` and `hover()` ?

Comment: I don't see where using `live` is a requirement. I got the impression that OP just wants to get it working, however that may be.

Comment: I see the code, but OP did not specify that using live was a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this (you could of course change the focus/blur events to mouse-events):

http://jsfiddle.net/BD7JA/2/

```
// <input value="BFA Offset" data-placeholder="BFA Offset" class="is-placeholder" />

$('[data-placeholder]').on({
  focus: function (evt) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('is-placeholder')) {
      $(this).val('');
      $(this).removeClass('is-placeholder');
    }
  },
  blur: function (evt) {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
      $(this).val($(this).data('placeholder'));
      $(this).addClass('is-placeholder');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".disappearOnClick").mouseenter( function (this) {
    if ($('#'+this.id).val() == 'BFA Offset') 
        $('#'+this.id).val('')
}).mouseleave( function (this) {
    if ($('#'+this.id).val() == '') 
        $('#'+this.id).val('BFA Offset')
});
```